# Invocation error on running application then crashes c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows forms application, and for some reason I'm getting an invocation error on `application.run` form1 why would this be? I have been scratching my head all day

```
namespace UserDataImport
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
           Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a `Target invocation error`

Comment: Please provide code of Form1, your shown code is not a problem.

Comment: The debugger just stops on the last line of code it has source code for.  Which is the Run() call.  You'll need to look at the rest of the call stack to have an idea what went wrong.  If you use a thread then use Debug + Windows + Threads to find the thread that called begin/invoke wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start debugging the program, on the VS press Debug->Exception. that will open a window like this:

[image]

mark the "common Language Runtime Exceptions"

now when the exception is thrown you should have a nicer look at what went wrong. then add the code that went wrong